# Accessing generated Custom Element in Svelte 3

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I'm using Svelte 3 with the option to generate Custom Elements with Shadow DOM but I can't figure out how to get a reference to the wrapper Custom Element (HTMLElement) so that I can attached event handlers and manipulate attributes. I have something like this:

```
<svelte:options tag="custom-button"/>

<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    function _onClick(e) {
        this.setAttribute('pressed', null);
    }

    var _boundClick = _onClick.bind(this);

    onMount((e) => {
        this.addEventListener('click', _boundClick);

        return () => {
            this.removeEventListener('click', _boundClick);
        };
    });
</script>

<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Other Styling */
</style>

<slot></slot>
```

The "this" bits don't work (they do in a normal vanilla Custom Element). Is there some Svelte specific way of getting a reference to the host element in a script?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

At present this isn't possible directly, though it would be a worthwhile addition. I've just [raised an issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3091).

The indirect approach would be to do `bind:this={element}` on the top-level element inside your custom element (assuming you have one), then you could do something long the lines of `$: host = element && element.parentNode.host`. You wouldn't have access to it upon initialisation, but it would be ready in `onMount`.

Comment: This worked for me.  However, one nitpick: host was still undefined in onMount, but it was available in a click handler (some nanoseconds later).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create an element that surrounds the slot, and then bind that to a variable using `bind:this={var}` as is shown in this example: https://svelte.dev/docs#Binding_a_DOM_node

so something like

```
<custom-button bind:this={customButton}>
<slot></slot>
</custom-button>
```

Then use that bound variable(`customButton`) that in the javascript, instead of `this` like so:

```
let customButton;

function _onClick(e) {
        customButton.setAttribute('pressed', null);
}
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the get_current_component function of svelte/internal

```
import { get_current_component } from 'svelte/internal';

let host = get_current_component();
```

I think that exporting this function would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution for this now, in the issue thread that Rich Harris linked to above.

You can use customElement's "extend" option to accomplish this:

```
<svelte:options
  customElement={{
    tag: 'custom-element',
    extend: (customElementConstructor) => {
      return class extends customElementConstructor {

        constructor() {
          super();
          this.host = this; // or this.shadowRoot, or whatever you need
        }
      };
    }
  }}
/>

<script>
  export let host;
</script>
```

Copied from this comment by "dummdidumm": https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3091#issuecomment-1642351615